# How to append Html in Jquery next method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the following HTML.

```
<td>
    <table class="position">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="position-numbers">
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
<td class="select-technique">
    <select class="technique-class">

    </select>
</td>

<td class="select-technique">
    <select  class="technique-class">

    </select>
</td>
<td class="select-technique">
    <select class="technique-class">

    </select>
</td>

<script>
let cloneTech = jquery('td').closest('select');
findNext.html(`<h1>hello</h1>`);
</script>
```

When I click on td I need to find very next select and append the html.
The next().html() is not working on this.

Comment: you want to add an option to select tag?

Comment: It seems like your html is wrong. You can't use `<td>` tag outside of `<table>` tag. Can you please update your question? Because right now are not clearly understood your requirements and expectations.

Comment: @dganenco a `<table>` tag can be used inside a `<td>` as long as both are enclosed inside a table. I think this is just a snippet of the code.

Answer (score 1):

closest only works upward in the dom, if you want to find elements that are nested in an element you need to use [.find('select')](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

This returns **all** elements that are inside an element, in your case you only have one select inside td so this should work for you.

you also shouldn't use `.html()` here because this sets the innerHTML, if you want to replace the select then use `.replace()`, if you want to insert it after the select, use `.after()`

```
let cloneTech = jquery('td').find('select');
findNext.after(`<h1>hello</h1>`);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you click td and you are using jquery, you can make the next:

```
 $(".select-technique").on("click", function(){ 
     $(this).children("select").html(`<h1>hello</h1>`);
  })
```

Or

```
  $(".select-technique").on("click", function(){ 
     $(this).find("select").html(`<h1>hello</h1>`);
  })
```

Comment: `html()` method will overwrite everything inside the select. Your result will be `<select><h1>hello</h1></select>`

Comment: yes, it was his original script, he is asking how to append , not which tags he needs to append inside a select. the logic tag must be <option> but ... he appended <h1>hello</h1> in the inicial question

Answer (score 1):

This will put the `h1` tag before the next `select` tag after you click a `td`.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('td').click(function () { 
            $(this).next().find('select').prepend('<h1>hello</h1>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

The html result of this `<select><h1>hello</h1></select>`. If you want the `h1` tags outside the select do this instead

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('td').click(function () { 
            $(this).next().find('select').before('<h1>hello</h1>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

The html result of this `<h1>hello</h1><select></select>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this below

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
  <td>
    <table class="position" border="1" cellpadding="5">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="position-numbers">
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
<td class="select-technique">
    <select class="technique-class">

    </select>
</td>

<td class="select-technique">
    <select  class="technique-class">

    </select>
</td>
<td class="select-technique">
    <select class="technique-class">

    </select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>

   $('td').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next('td.select-technique').find('select').css('background','yellow').html('<option>Options</option>');
})
<script>
```

See the jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/mgnwvrpj/3/